# XcodeCapp complains about NSToolbarPrint when using Toolbar in Interface Builder

Tags: interface-builder, cappuccino

Since I moved from Cappuccino 0.9.6 to 0.9.7, XcodeCapp gives me the error 'The built in image "NSToolbarPrint" is not supported' when there is a toolbar in Interface Builder. Removing the print item doesn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that an error or just a warning though? You probably didn't fully remove the print item from the toolbar though - did you remove it from only the toolbar itself, or did you also remove it from the palette of available toolbar items? When you double click the toolbar in Xcode you should be able to see the whole palette and delete the 'NSToolbarPrint' item there too.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I also had to remove the color picker and font picker icon in order to avoid the error.